# Building a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, iteration

I'm trying to build a matrix in numpy. The matrix dimensions should be (5001x7). Here is my code:

```
S=np.array([.0788,.0455,.0222,.0042,.0035,.0029,.0007])
#This is vector S, comprised of 7 scalars.

lamb=list(range(0,5001))
#This is a list of possible values for lambda, a parameter in my data.

M = np.empty([5001,7], order='C')
#This is the empty matrix which is to be filled in the iterations below.

for i in S:
    for j in lamb:
         np.append(M,((S[i]**2)/(lamb[j]+S[i]**2)))
```

The problem I'm having is that M remains a matrix of zero vectors.

Important details:
1) I've assigned the final line as:

```
    M=np.append(M,((S[i]**2)/(lamb[j]+S[i]**2)))
```

I then get an array of values of length 70,014 in a 1d array. I'm not really sure what to make of it.

2) I've already tried switching the dtype parameter between 'float' and 'int' for matrix M.

3) I receive this warning when I run the code:
VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  app.launch_new_instance()

4) I'm working in Python 3.4

I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think `np.append` is doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `append` adds to the end of the array, which is why your final array has `5001x7x2=70014` elements. Only the first half is zeros.  It flattens the array to 1D because you didn't specify an `axis` to append.

2) A much more "numpy" way to do this whole process is broadcasting

```
S=np.array([.0788,.0455,.0222,.0042,.0035,.0029,.0007])
lamb=np.arange(0,5001)
M=(S[:,None]**2)/(lamb[None,:]+S[:,None]**2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I voted yours solution as the answer because I learned a little about numpy broadcasting. It's a very nice way to fill the matrix. Thanks for explaining why mode code had failed as well. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`np.append` makes a copy of the array and appends values to the end of the copy (making the array larger each time), whereas I think you want to modify `M` in place:

```
 for i in range(len(S)):
     for j in range(len(lamb)):
          M[j][i] = ((S[i]**2)/(lamb[j]+S[i]**2))
```

Comment: Thank you for responding back to me so quickly and explanation why my code was failing. Your solution works just as fine.